# Concrete5 Form Dynamic From Email

Tags: concrete5

I'm using the default Form block for a simple contact form. But, instead of the email always coming from the same (admin) email, I would like to have it dynamically pull the email provided by the user filling in the contact form. Would this be very hard? I'm already asking for their email...I just need to grab that response and set it as the "From" field when the email is sent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/add-ability-in-contact-form-to-reply-to-the-submitter/

UPDATE: Above link is broken, you can find the how-to here: https://legacy-documentation.concrete5.org/tutorials/add-ability-in-contact-form-to-reply-to-the-submitter

Comment: This solution is good but not complete. In fact, you also have to test if there is zero, one or several "email inputs" in the form.

Comment: @nico_somb, I assume the OP only has a single email field in their form. If not, then they will obviously have to modify the code to pull out the proper field, but this was not specified in his question. Also note that the code will actually work if there's more than one field -- it will just wind up using the value of the last email field it finds. And if there are zero email fields in the form, well... then how would it matter if the from address was missing since there isn't one to use?

Comment: The posted URL is now a 404 :-(

Comment: *sigh*, they moved all the old docs without putting in redirects from the old urls... updated the answer with new link